# How to manage Error: kernel conflict with offline repo on RHEL7?

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, yum, dependencies

I'm following the HowTo [Active/Passive MySQL High Availability Pacemaker Cluster with DRBD on CentOS 7](https://www.lisenet.com/2016/activepassive-mysql-high-availability-pacemaker-cluster-with-drbd-on-centos-7/) in order to install MariaDB in cluster mode on RHEL7.

In my case I do not have access to internet on the DB server, so I had to create an offline repo from a CentOs 7 to download only all RPMs and dependencies :

```
sudo yum -y install yum-plugin-downloadonly createrepo    
mkdir -p repo/CentOS/7/local/x86_64/RPMS/
sudo yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=repo/CentOS/7/local/x86_64/RPMS/ pcs kmod-drbd84 drbd84-utils mariadb-server mariadb
createrepo repo/CentOS/7/local/x86_64
```

To create an correct offline repo, I installed a CentOs7 (minimal mode) with the same linux kernel as my RHEL7 : `3.10.0-327.el7x86_64`. 
The repo was created just after the CentOs7 was installed (without yum update).

After installing the repo on RHEL7, I'm able to download and install successfully `pcs, drbd84-utils mariadb-server mariadb` but I'm facing issue with `kmod-drbd84`.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 (offline_maria)
       Requires: linux-firmware >= 20170606-55
       Installed: linux-firmware-20150904-43.git6ebf5d5.el7.noarch
(@anaconda/7.2)
           linux-firmware = 20150904-43.git6ebf5d5.el7
Error: Package: kernel-3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 (offline_maria)
       Requires: dracut >= 033-502
       Installed: dracut-033-359.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.2)
           dracut = 033-359.el7
Error: kernel conflicts with xfsprogs-3.2.2-2.el7.x86_64
Error: kernel conflicts with kexec-tools-2.0.7-38.el7.x86_64
Error: kernel conflicts with kmod-20-5.el7.x86_64
```

I do not have any issue with Linux Firmware and dracut as an upgrade should resolved it but I'm worried about the `Error: kernel conflicts` and the stability of the system with this method.

What `Error: kernel conflicts` really stand for?

What is the best way to get rid off?

Comment: Have you used reposync for the local repo synchronization? Or some different method?

Comment: @JaroslavKucera It's the first time I'm using offline repo and I've used createrepo (I'm adding in the post the exact command I used).

Comment: Well, I've never used the --downloadonly path, but your repo seems to have unsatisfied dependencies. I'd suggest to create complete local repo image  with reposync && createrepo.